# Centering an individual character with DrawString

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, centering, drawstring

I have tried all of the suggested ways to center text, but I can't seem to get the results I want while centering an individual character.

I have a rectangle.  In that rectangle I'm drawing a circle with DrawEllipse.  Now I want to draw a single character inside the circle using the same rectangle and DrawString, to have it perfectly centered.

Here is my basic code:

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(xImage))
{
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

    g.FillEllipse(fillBrush, imageRect.X, imageRect.Y, imageRect.Width - 1, imageRect.Height - 1);

    g.DrawString(Text, font, Brushes.White, imageRect, stringFormat);
}
```

The text is centered horizontally... but it's not properly centered veritcally.  Using a symmetrical character like an uppercase "I", I find that the top of the character is always much nearer to the edge of the rectangle than the bottom of the character.  The distance is probably at least a 50% increase.

I assume that it is measuring enough space for characters like a lowercase "j" which hangs lower.  However, since I am trying to create a graphical icon with a single letter, I want more precise centering.

Comment: Have you compares the results of the DrawString method to those of the TextRenderer.DrawText method with TextFormatFlags of HoriztonalCenter and VerticalCenter?

Comment: No repro.  Beware that an uppercase I doesn't have a descender like the character g.

Comment: I tried TextRenderer.DrawText and got similar results.

Comment: Hans: My point is that when I draw characters which don't have descenders, they are being vertically centered in a way that provides blank space for the nonexistant descenders.  Thus, the character is not really centered.

Comment: I am assuming the GDI has no way to do this, so what I am going to do is measure the text, create a Bitmap the size of the measure, draw the text on the bitmap, lock the bits, and get the bounding area of the sub-Rectangle which actually contains data (non-transparent pixels).  Then bit blit that rectangle in a centered position over the first Rectangle.  Should work I think, but the performance will be awful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `GraphicsPath` to accomplish the size calculation.

```
public static void DrawCenteredText(Graphics canvas, Font font, float size, Rectangle bounds, string text)
{
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, size, new Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    // Determine physical size of the character when rendered
    var area = Rectangle.Round(path.GetBounds());

    // Slide it to be centered in the specified bounds
    var offset = new Point(bounds.Left + (bounds.Width / 2 - area.Width / 2) - area.Left, bounds.Top + (bounds.Height / 2 - area.Height / 2) - area.Top);
    var translate = new Matrix();
    translate.Translate(offset.X, offset.Y);
    path.Transform(translate);

    // Now render it however desired
    canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    canvas.FillPath(SystemBrushes.ControlText, path);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty genius.  I'll try it out.

Comment: @ccnyou is right, this is perfect! I tried with `MeasureString` but without any luck. Today I found this answer. Question is old, but problem was actual. This fixed it immediately!

Comment: Very cool! +1 - GraphicsPath is so underrated (together with Label..) ;-)

Comment: This should have more attention, I seached hours for this :)

Comment: I lost too much sleep trying to use "MeasureString" on Wingdings to create a sort of char-map. The behavior was odd and my math wasnt working. This worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

you got

[image]

instead

[image]

hope this helps

Comment: Notice in your images that the "g" is not centered.  I'm not looking for typographical centering, I'm not drawing words where the characters need to be aligned.  I'm drawing a single character and I want it to be in the exact center on the circle regardless of which character it is.  Think of how a graphic designer would make an icon in Photoshop by centering it.  I need to do that programmatically.

Comment: Ok, I've lost, John Arlen has the perfect answer!

Comment: It should be 
    StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic());

Answer (score 1):

Though John Arlen's answer is perfect, I'd like to post my answer:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         // Set up string.
        string measureString = "HelloWorld";
        Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 100, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Measure string.
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
        stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

        // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 10.0F, 10.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

        // Draw string to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, 10f + stringSize.Height / 12.0f));
    }
```

code result like that:
[image: result in my computer]

"HelloWorld" is centered vertically in the red box.

For the height of descender line is approximately equal 1/6 of `stringSize.Height` calculated by `MeasureString`

---

### | top padding 1/6

### | word body 3/6

### | word descender 1/6

### | bottom padding 1/6